# No data in cursor

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, insert

I´ve got an application that reads and writes in a SQLITE-database.

```
public void insertkind(int id, String name, String geburtsdatum, String geschlecht){
        long rowId = 1;
        try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(NAME, name);
        cv.put(GEBURTSDATUM, geburtsdatum);
        cv.put(GESCHLECHT, geschlecht);
        try{
            rowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME_KIND, null, cv);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("DES DERF MA NEEEEEEEEEEED SENG!!!!");
        }

        db.close();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "insert()", e);
    }
    finally{
        Log.d(TAG, "rowId");
    }
}
```

With the following code I want to select the data from the database:

```
public Cursor select(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_KIND, new String[] {"_id", "name", "geburtsdatum", "geschlecht"}, 
                "" + "", null, null, null, null);
        System.out.println(cursor.getCount());
        return cursor;
    }
```

I also used a similiar code in a different application. My problem is that `cursor.getCount()` is 0, but there are no Exceptions when I insert the data. `name`, `geburtsdatum` and `geschlecht` all have some values.

I can´t check the database with adb because it doesn´t work on my computer. 
What is the problem?

Comment: How do you know that there is no exception when inserting?

Comment: Add more debug logging so you know exactly what is going on, or step through it with a debugger. And don't filter the logcat you might miss something important/valuable.

Answer (score 1):

If your `cursor.getCount()` get's 0 your query execute on database.

I think problem may be in where clause , try set `null` instead `"" + ""`

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME_KIND, new String[] {"_id", "name", "geburtsdatum", "geschlecht"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

While I believe what Jurac posted will work, just a couple of questions:

1. Why are you not inserting the id?
2. What are you trying to do with ""+""?

If you are trying to obtain ALL rows without any filtering with the 4 column names you listed, then yes, pass null.

As an alternative, try using a raw Query

```
    String queryString = "SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_NAME_KIND";
```

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);